# Certificate Purpose, when is it validated?

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate

I was troubleshooting an issue today where a user was being presented with "Invalid Server Certificate" in Google Chrome when attempting to connect to a site.  We validated the SSL chain, the certificate, validated connectivity, and nothing appeared to be wrong.  an openssl s_client connect similarly did not appear to be a problem.  We even ran a tcpdump, and while I'm not particularly familiar with reading them, I saw no obvious errors.

Eventually, just for grins, I opened the link in Firefox to verify I wasn't somehow getting a cached copy, and I received a new error "Certificate type not approved for application.".  At that point, it was a very quick look to see that our server cert was provisioned as a client cert.  Problem solved.

My question is, at what point in the process is the purpose validated?  I feel that I should have seen this error in the tcpdump, or especially the openssl s_client connect.  I'm wondering if the cert purpose isn't checked until later.

If it helps, the request was going from a Netscaler vserver to a WebSEAL instance.

Comment: Apparently somebody felt that I did not put enough research into this question or it was unclear.  If that person could let me know what was unclear so I can avoid making this mistake in the future, that would be helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's validated by the client, not the protocol.  Part of the protocol is to transfer the public portion of the cert, which includes metadata like acceptable uses.  It's then up to the client to decide if the certificate is valid for the use case the application is executing.  The protocol has no way of knowing what the application type is, or what the full set of uses are (this was metadata that was added in later in the development of the standard).

This is why openssl doesn't care, but chrome / ff does.

Comment: Appreciate the response.  It's very helpful to know when these things get processed.